# Cadtool and spline plugins not working using QGIS

Tags: qgis, plugins, cad

Am trying to edit a line shapefile using a spline tool in QGIS 2.4.0 .It is drawing but the ok button is inactive.

what could be the problem?

Generally am trying to create a curved line.

Comment: After installing the Spline tool plug in and drawing a shape, RIGHT CLICK to accept the current shape/nodes. Also note that the plugin only works if the project is in a Projected Coordinate System. Otherwise you will digitize a normal line.

Answer (score 3):

I discoverd the answer to this question, just check the option for ”suppress attribute form pop-up after feature creation” found in settings-options-digitizing-feature creation.